# MSSQL Server maximum users and privileges

Tags: sql-server

I have a design question.
We have to troubleshoot a custom application due to timeouts in the database connection. The application is hosted within a Sharepoint plattform, which has a timeout of 30 seconds set. But the timeout is not the root cause.

We suspect the root cause in how the application handles users and authorizations.

The users are authenticated against an active directory and are kind of registered within the MSSQL Server, so each user will also have its own account in the database. For each user and stored procedure/view, the application grants privileges within the database.

So in the end it uses the mechanisms of the database to enforce read and write access rights.

*Edit:*
The application allows to define roles dynamically to separate privileges for different organizations. These organizations are known to the application only.
But these roles are not reflected in the database. Instead they are converted into single privileges for each database object.

Currently we have 1300 users and about 4000 privileges.
And currently a query to show properties/privileges for one user takes about 1-1,5 minutes.

Does the MSSQL Server have some limitations in terms of maximum suggested amount of user accounts and privileges since too many accounts and privileges may cause performance issues?

Comment: Are you aware that SQL Server has Windows authentication/authorization built in?

Comment: I don't know that it does have a maximum, but have you considered using AD groups? You can add Logins and Users for AD groups just like a Windows account (they work exactly the same way). if you have 1,300 accounts, but you could easily divide these into distinct permissions, create AD groups for all those permissions, add the accounts to that AD group, Create Logins and Users (on your SQL Server: `CREATE LOGIN [Domain\AD Group] FROM WINDOWS...;`) for those AD groups, then the permissions. Then, finally, after all working, drop all the individual Logins and users.

Comment: @Yuck: I missed to tell, that the application is hosted within a Sharepoint environment, so yes, windows authentication is used I suppose, but not for authorization. In the end the question remains, if SQL Server has some limitations in handling that amount of users and privileges.

Comment: @Lamu: the application allows to define roles dynamically to separate privileges for different organizations, but these roles are not reflected in the database but are converted into single privileges for each database object. These organizations are known to the application only. So in order to use AD groups, the AD would have to allow the application to define application specific groups. And the application would need to be able to check the Ad groups a user is in. Your suggestion seems to be a good approach. I will check if that is possible.